# How to make a android app to MultiScreen support?

Tags: android

I hav an existing android app in version 1.5 . I have to make it to support Multiscreen .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you have** already developed and published an application for Android 1.5 or earlier, you should read this document and consider how you may need to adapt your application for proper display on new devices that offer different screens and that are running Android 1.6 or later. In most cases, only minor adjustments are needed, however you should make sure to test your application on all supported screens.

**Document:**

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I developed a application on Android 2.1 and used relative layout for UI in xml files.In manifeast file added  <supports-screens> tag and make it true for screen size. Is it sufficent for multiscreen suport?

Answer (score 0):

That can be done very easily, here is the library which you need to implement on your project. I created this library using this you can support all the screens.

https://github.com/Shekhar14o3/Library-On-Different-Screen-Supports